# What data structure to use for reading CSV like files in C++?

Tags: c++, csv, join, hash, hashtable

My task is to implement a hash join algorithm with tables (.txt files) provided in the program arguments.

A table files could look like this:

```
c1:int,c2:int,c3:string,c4:long
1,1,asd,11
2,3,asdqwe,11
```

A header row, with the name of the column and type of the column, and then the rows delimited by ",".
The number of columns and the type of the columns are variable.

So the column name and type should be stored, and I must store these in a 2D array or matrix.

I have to read the type and make a container for the column of the specified type. 
I also have to store all the columns together in a heterogeneous array or struct.

I don't know any of the STL containers below C++11 what is heterogenous.

How can I determinate the type of a column, create a container from its type and store all the column arrays in a heterogeneous way?

My try-hards:

```
 class Table {
public:
    struct Column {
        std::string name;
        std::string type;

        Column(std::string name, std::string type) : name(name), type(type) {}
    };

    //enum for switch-case
    static enum typeValue {
        INT,
        STRING,
        LONG,
        CHAR,
        DOUBLE,
        SHORT
    };


private:
    std::string filePath;
    std::ifstream file;
    std::vector<Column> columns;
    int rowNumber;
    std::vector<std::array> tableData;

public:
    Table(std::string filePath) {
        this->filePath = filePath;
        rowNumber = 0;
        open();
        loadTableData();


    }


    bool open() {

        file.open(filePath);
        std::string line;
        std::string delimiter = ",";
        size_t pos = 0;
        std::string token;
        getline(file, line);
        while ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {     //parse the columns
            token = line.substr(0, pos);
            size_t posT = 0;
            posT = token.find(":");
            columns.push_back(Column(token.substr(0, posT), token.substr(posT + delimiter.length())));
            line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }
        size_t posT = 0;
        posT = line.find(":");
        columns.push_back(Column(line.substr(0, posT), line.substr(posT + delimiter.length())));

        while (std::getline(file, line))    //count the rows
            ++rowNumber;

        for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); ++i) {

            switch (hashIt(columns[i].type)) {
                case INT:
                    std::vector<int> *tempI = new std::vector<int>();
                    tableData[i] = tempI;
                    break;
                case STRING:
                    std::vector<std::string> *tempS = new std::vector<std::string>();
                    tableData[i] = tempS;
                    break;
                case LONG:
                    std::vector<long> *tempL = new std::vector<long>();
                    tableData[i] = tempL;
                    break;
                case CHAR:
                    std::vector<char> *tempC = new std::vector<char>();
                    tableData[i] = tempC;
                    break;
                case DOUBLE:
                    std::vector<double> *tempD = new std::vector<double>();
                    tableData[i] = tempD;
                    break;
                case SHORT:
                    std::vector<short> *tempSh = new std::vector<short>();
                    tableData[i] = tempSh;
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cerr << "Error: Unsupported column type.";
            }


        }

        //file.close();

        std::cout << "Table " << filePath << " has " << columns.size() << " columns." << std::endl;

        return true;


    }

    bool loadTableData() {
        file.seekg(0, file.beg);
        std::string line;
        getline(file, line); //discarding the column headers

        while (std::getline(file, line)) {
            ++rowNumber;        //count the rows

            for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); ++i) {

                std::string delimiter = ",";
                size_t pos = line.find(delimiter);
                std::string token = line.substr(0, pos);
                tableData[i].push_back(token);


            }
        }

    }

    template<typename T>

    T **createColumnData(int colNum) {
        T *data = new T[rowNumber]();
        tableData.insert(colNum, data);
    }


    typeValue hashIt(std::string const &inString) {
        if (inString == "int") return INT;
        if (inString == "string") return STRING;
        if (inString == "long") return LONG;
        if (inString == "char") return CHAR;
        if (inString == "double") return DOUBLE;
        if (inString == "short") return SHORT;
        std::cerr << "Error: Unsupported column type.";


        return NULL;

    }


};
```

Thank you!

Comment: You may use `std::variant` to store the data.

Comment: As far as I know it is implemented only in C++14. I have to use C++89 and 11.

Comment: then use `boost::variant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you should model a row as a structure:

```
struct Row
{
  int column1;
  int column2;
  std::string name;
  int column3;
};
```

Next step would be to overload `operator>>` to read in the structure.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Row& r)
{
  char comma;
  inp >> r.column1;
  inp >> comma;
  inp >> r.column2;
  inp >> comma;
  std::getline(inp, r.name, ',');
  inp >> r.column3;
  inp.ignore(100000, '\n');
  return inp;
}
```

Then you could read the records:

```
std::vector<Row> database;
Row r;
while (input_file >> r)
{
  database.push_back(r);
}
```

Maybe your next step would be to create index tables.  This would allow faster searches of your database:

```
std::map<int, int> index_by_column1;
std::map<std::string, int> index_by_name;
```

The second value of the pair is an index into the database of the associated record.

To find a record containing the `name` "Fred":

```
std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator iter;
iter = index_by_name.find("Fred");
Record r;
if (iter != index_by_name.end())
{
  int database_index = (*iter).second;
  r = database[database_index];
}
```

Rather than using a `std::map`, you could use a hash table that returns an index into the database.

Comment: Thanks the answer! As I said the type and the number of the columns are not fix. The other table could ben string,int,string,string. So I can not asign a static struct like the one you wrote.

Comment: @fzsombor: In my experience, creating a generic table is difficult.  You could create a `Record` structure and a `Field` parent class.  A `Record` would be a container of `Field` pointers.  You would use inheritance for the `Field` class, but `Field` should have common methods for fields.